# global_assumptions and sqrt simplification in sympy

Tags: python, sympy, simplify, sqrt

I'm simplifying expression like `sqrt(a**2*b**2)` for positive `a` and `b` hoping to get `a*b`.
The so called "old style" of setting the assumptions seems to works ok. But usage of `global_assumptions` object, as well as `assuming` technology fails in rather simple cases. For some reason the "new style" is preferrable for me. Any idea, what am I doing wrong?

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.assumptions.assume import global_assumptions

x = Symbol('x', positive=True)
f = Function('f', positive=True)

y = Symbol('y')
g = Function('g')
global_assumptions.add(Q.positive(y), Q.positive(g(y)))

print(refine(sqrt(x**2))) #ok
print(refine(sqrt(y**2))) #ok
print(refine(sqrt(f(x)**2))) #ok
print(refine(sqrt(g(y)**2))) #ok

print(refine(sqrt(x**2*f(x)**2))) #ok
print(refine(sqrt(y**2*f(x)**2))) #ok
print(refine(sqrt(x**2*g(y)**2))) #ok
print(refine(sqrt(y**2*g(y)**2))) # doesn't work - no simplification
```

Comment: Look at the expressions that you are passing into `refine`: `sqrt(y**2*f(x)**2)` comes out as an `Abs`. It looks like refine doesn't handle the sqrt of a product. Some of the examples above work because they partly work without using refine (the old assumptions affect the evaluation of expressions).

Comment: But `sqrt(y**2)` gives `sqrt(y**2)`, though `refine(sqrt(y**2))` gives `y`. So `refine` helps somehow. For old style assumptions it removes unnecessary `Abs`. But I can't understand its behavior for the new cases.

Comment: I think that the implementation of refine is just missing the abilty to handle this.